# SpringBoot: Testing the Service layer

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

Let's assume that I have two classes:

1. TodoRepository
2. TodoService

the `TodoRepository` is a simple CRUD Repository:

```
public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
}
```

the `TodoService` is just a class which calls this Repository:

```
@Service
public class TodoService{

    private final TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TodoService(TodoRepository todoRepository) {
        this.todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }

    public void createTodo(Todo todo) {
        todoRepository.save(todo);
    }
}
```

Should I bother testing the service layer?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the explanation from @Dherik. I created a test class which looks like:

*Note:* I am using JUnit5, Mockito and Spring framework

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class TodoServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    private TodoService todoService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        todoService = new TodoService(todoRepository);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        clearInvocations(tanklevelRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void createTodo() {
        todoService.createTodo(new Todo());

        // verify if the save method is called when createTodo is called too
        verify(todoRepository, times(1)).save(any(Todo.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you should. I believe any code that you write yourself requires testing. There are usually in-memory deployments of databases that you can use (i.e. fongo for mongodb) to test this. We test any custom repository implementation in unit tests

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's important.

Even now being a very simple class, maybe some developer on the future could add some weird condition on this method `createTodo` that the `Todo` is not saved anymore.

If you write a test for the actual method to verify if the `save` is called, the developer will be advised about the situation if he makes some change that affect the `Todo` save.

See a pseudo test example:

```
@Test
public void createTodo() {

    TodoRepository todoRepository = mock(TodoRepository.class);

    TodoService todoService = new TodoService(todoRepository);
    todoService.createTodo(new Todo());
    
    // verify if the save method is called when createTodo is called too
    verify(todoRepository, times(1)).save(any(Todo.class));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this kind of thing tested with Junit using a Mock framework and injecting a mock repo into the service, then checking the mock repo was called. That seems really pointless to me as the test knows too much about the implementation. If you change the implementation you have to rewrite the test, so it's no use for refactoring.

I would test this kind of thing with an integration test that treated the app like a black box. i.e. start the app, trigger whatever creates a todo and check that it was created. I'd probably use cucumber-jvm and have a scenario with a step to create a todo and another to retrieve it.

I think you should create tests that

- help you write reliable code
- allow refactoring without the need to rewrite tests
- prove the application does what it's supposed to